# How are they displaying one character for other

Tags: firefox, unicode, cross-browser

Please see [this page](http://te.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%B0%8B%E0%B0%97%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B5%E0%B1%87%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81_-_%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A1%E0%B0%B2%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81_1_-_%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%82%E0%B0%95%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%A4%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81_1) and guide me:

```
http://te.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%B0%8B%E0%B0%97%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B5%E0%B1%87%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81_-_%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A1%E0%B0%B2%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81_1_-_%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%82%E0%B0%95%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%A4%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81_1
```

In the last but one line,
స నః పితేవ సూనవే ऽగ్నే సూపాయనో భవ |
they are actually using this: ऽ, but getting ఽ in my firefox browser. How is it possible? But, safari is not showing like that. It just looks normal, ऽ.

Another thing is my firefox browser can't show this unicode character properly, it gives a box, as you may see above, but not there, in wikisource! They are getting perfect symbol.

Are they showing an image?

If I see view source, it just looks ऽ.
Is it a trick of css or javascript or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a font issue.

Wikisource doesn't specify a specific font for the text, but uses a generic

```
font-family: sans-serif;
```

I assume Safari and Firefox choose different fonts as the standard sans-serif font on your system, with different characters for `ऽ`. Why that is, I can't tell you because I'm not familiar with the [Telugu alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_language). Are these characters interchangeable, is this a merely stylistic difference?

On my system (Windows 7 64-bit), I get `ऽ` in all browsers (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox).